# Error Column "Column Name" Doesn't Belong To The Table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, datatable

I'm trying to retrieve data from the table `Student` and store the values into a list of `Student` objects. While doing so, I'm encountering with error

> Column 'Id' doesn't belong to the table

I really don't understand where I'm going wrong. Please help.

```
private List<Student> GetAllStudents
{
    get
    {
        students = new List<Student>();

        com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student");
        // com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        com.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = com;
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            st = new Student();

            st.Id = Int32.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString());
            st.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            st.Year = Int32.Parse(dr["Year"].ToString());
            st.Dept = dr["Dept"].ToString();
            st.Place = dr["Place"].ToString();

            students.Add(st);
        }

        return students;
    }
}
```

This is how my table schema looks like

```
public class Student {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Year { get; set; }
     public string Dept { get; set; }
     public string Place { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a column called `Id` on the `Student` table?  The runtime thinks there isn't, and it's usually right about these things.

Comment: @David I have the column Id and even the types are similar (Int)

Comment: Well, you say that... But the runtime says otherwise.  When you debug this, what are the column names available in `dr`?

Comment: @David Got david. Was having another mdf file which had the same column name Id. Thanks! :)

Comment: I guess the right column name is StudentId.